# Why doesn't my interface inherit?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I must be doing something wrong

```
public interface IActor
{
    //actor stuff
}

public class BaseShip : IActor
{
    //base ship stuff
}

public class PlayerShip: BaseShip
{
    //Only the stuff for this particular ship
}
```

Why then doesn't this work:

```
IActor player = new PlayerShip();
```

Or

```
List<IActor> actors = new List<IActor>(){new PlayerShip()};
```

I get Cannot convert from [PlayerShip] to [IActor]

*note: snipped code for brevity*

---

#### Update

I accidently defined the interface in two different namespaces. Nothing more to it.

Comment: What's the exact problem/error you get? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: See top of OP. I should probably take a break ;) Do feel free to help me close it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you certain this is your structure? I copied and pasted your code and the actions compiled and ran fine for me.

EDIT:

You guys need to step back for a second...interfaces certainly do propogate down the chain of inheritance. You're telling me that an inherited control doesn't implement IDisposable?

Comment: Damn, It appears I defined the IActor at two different namespaces by accident. Will close the topic. Sorry

Comment: @boris: No, only users with 3k or higher can vote to close.